# Potential problem with a question of AP and it's sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ be an AP such that:
$$\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_p}{a_1+a_2+...+a_q}=\frac{p^3}{q^3};p\neq q$$
Then what is $\frac{a_6}{a_{21}}$

- First sum of an AP of n terms is a polynomial of degree 2 in n, but here it is 3.
- Let $\frac{a_1}{a_1+a_2}=\frac{1^3}{2^3}=\frac18\implies a_1=\alpha,a_2=7\alpha$. Similiarly, $a_3=19\alpha$, but it isn't AP now?
- If we remove the AP restriction, we get using second point: $\frac{a_6}{a_{21}}=\frac{91}{1261}$

But answer given is $121/1681$ which is close by $\approx0.0001839$

Consider my question: **Is this above question corretc in defining such an AP**

Comment: What is "AP"?  ?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Arithematic Progression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such AP exists, we have $$\frac{a_6}{a_{21}}=\frac{41S_{11}}{11S_{41}}=\frac{121}{1681},$$ where $S_n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$.
But I doubt the existence of that.

Comment: can you make out that it is surely an AP?

Comment: I can guarantee **NO** AP satisfies the identity.